# Display data from observable list in tableview javafx

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

i have this code

```
ObservableList data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
data.addAll(itemNumber, "Not Verified", "");

mItemNoColumn.setCellValueFactory (value -> SimpleObjectProperty<>(data.get(0)));
mStatusColumn.setCellValueFactory (value -> SimpleObjectProperty<>(data.get(1)));

mTableView.getItems().add(data);
```

Assume that all variables are already declared and initialized.

The output given by that code in the tableview is it is only getting the last value of the ObservableList and not all the data needed.

But when i print the observable list in the console, all the data needed is printed correctly.

The expected output in the tableview should be all the items inside the observable list

Answer (score 1):

The cell value factory is used for each cell in a `TableColumn`. This means when you explicitly use `data` (which is just one row of your table) in the factories you have inadvertently tied every cell (i.e. every row) to that one `data` object. The `CellDataFeatures` object passed to the factory gives you access to the row's item its trying to grab the value for. Your code should look more like:

```
mItemNoColumn.setCellValueFactory(features -> Bindings.valueAt(features.getValue(), 0));
mStatusColumn.setCellValueFactory(features -> Bindings.valueAt(features.getValue(), 1));
```

I used [`Bindings.valueAt(ObservableList,int)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#valueAt(javafx.collections.ObservableList,int)) because it will update if you change the value at that index of the `ObservableList`. However, if you don't need that you can continue wrapping the value in an `ObjectProperty`.

You don't provide much context so I can't be sure where this code is called, but remember you only need to set the `cellValueFactory` *once*.

Comment: i tried using your approach, but the output is still the same.